# can not install specific version of nltk

Tags: python, pip, nltk

for a specific reason I need to install nltk 2.09b in python 2.7 version. But whenever I execute the following command,

```
pip2 install nltk==2.0b9
```

I get the following error:

```
Collecting nltk==2.0b9
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ea/b3/4c5157bf034437905fbbd3c80e58c8b4a22cf3400db0bdf19dae3079a732/nltk-2.0b9.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/private/var/folders/3b/yskb8jks10lf_pqvv1sy7v740000gn/T/pip-install-63jdDZ/nltk/setup.py'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/3b/yskb8jks10lf_pqvv1sy7v740000gn/T/pip-install-63jdDZ/nltk/
```

But if I run without any version specification I don't get an error. like the following:

```
pip2 install nltk;
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried downloading the .tar.gz, extracting it and then doing `python2 setup.py install` in the extracted directory, i.e. performing a manual installation?

Answer (score 1):

First thing: using anaconda, you probably have a recent enough pip and setuptools and should use conda itself to update those. With anaconda, conda install is the primary resource for installing anaconda-provided packages. Then, "2.0b9" is a beta release (as indicated by the "b9") and might suffer from a configuration problem for the install. The setup.py file is not located at the root of the downloaded archive file, I suppose that creates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
pip3.6 install nltk==version
```